# Visual Studio does not close IE window (and vice versa)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Hopefully this is the correct place to ask but I have an unusual issue.  I have Visual Studio 2017 (community).  I find that when I start debugging an asp.net project, it opens IE correctly but when I stop debugging it does not close the IE window.  Conversely when I close the IE window it does not stop debugging.

Debugging is working so they are communicating with each other.

Any ideas why this might be happening?   Windows 10.   Thanks!

Comment: They are separate processes and close event isn't sent between the two processes.

Comment: yes that's how its acting but not how it's supposed to act.   Every other installation like this works as expected.